# Resetting MYSQL root password - ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to reset my root password and have followed various examples with no joy.

I'm trying to follow https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html, have stopped my mysql server and restarted with --skip-grant-tables

I then login and change my root PW:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ''

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I then stop the server and restart without the skip grant tables flag, however still can't login with root user and no password.

I've also tried editing my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file to look like:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[client]
user=root
password=""

[mysql]
user=root
password=""

[mysqldump]
user=root
password=""

[mysqldiff]
user=root
password=""
```

Other methods I've tried include stopping mysql and restarting with

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

However after that apparently succefully starts I cannot connect to mysql on that socket

```
 mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've tried specifying the socket in my.cnf with no joy

The most frustrating part is this isn't a new installation - I've run mysql without a root password locally for a few months now, and this morning it randomly failed to connect

Any help is greatly appreciated